# I want to put the x and y values obtained by the script below in the script address above, but I don't know why it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I want to put the x and y values obtained by the script below in the script address above, but I don't know why it doesn't work. query: $("#z").Val() is applied well, but I don't know why x and y are not allowed.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://search/keyword.json?",
        data: { y: $("#y").val() ,  x: $("#x").val() , query: $("#z").val() },
        headers: {Authorization: ""},
    })
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<div id="x" value="" type="text"><x> </x></div>
<div id="y" value="" type="text"><y> </y></div>

<script>
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                console.log(position.coords.longitude);
                $( "y" ).append("<strong>"+position.coords.latitude+"</strong>" );
                $( "x" ).append("<strong>"+position.coords.longitude+"</strong>" );
            }, function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }, {
                enableHighAccuracy: false,
                maximumAge: 0,
                timeout: Infinity
            });
            } else {
            alert('can't find you');
            }
        }
        getLocation();
</script>
```

Comment: `div` doesn't have `.val()` you can get its value using `.text()`

Comment: OMG OMG OMG SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO THANK YOU!!!!! Thank you for saving the person at the beginning of coding.